# cascading : How to read or write multicharactor word?

Tags: cascading

If 'Each' read GBK String from file and Write GBK String to file, how can i do? How to define it?

```
Fields namesFields = new Fields("zid", "vid", "title", "number");
sourcePipe = new Each(sourcePipe, new Fields("line"), new Parse(namesFields), Fields.ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

On Feb 27, 2013, at 11:24pm, chen dong wrote:

> If i want to read String (format: GBK) and Write String(format: GBK).
>   How can i do?

http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.1/javadoc/cascading/scheme/hadoop/TextLine.html

Use the constructor with charsetName parameter.

Comment: I also ask this question in Google groups, and at there someone answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Each is used to perform a [function](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/1.2/userguide/html/ch05s02.html) or [filter](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/1.2/userguide/html/ch05s03.html) on input data.

if you have data in columns like `"zid", "vid", "title", "number"`,

you can perform filter on one of those columns .like you can filter data if column title is not having jdk string.

so that tuple with jdk string will be printed as output .

for that you have to write a [user defined filter](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/1.2/userguide/html/ch05s03.html) by implementing `filter` interface and extending `baseoperation` class.